# Django Nginx Media Folder for User Upload/Download

Tags: django, nginx, django-rest-framework, nginx-config

As part of an app I am working on with Django DRF and Vue, I have a section for uploading and downloading files. Files get uploaded to a media folder and are displayed as a list where users can download them. This all works fine in development running 'python manage.py run server' and 'npm run serve' but I am getting mixed results deploying it on Nginx with Docker.

I have tried every configuration possible. Currently, uploading and showing as a list is working without issue. When trying to download the files I am getting a 404 not found error. It is using the correct URL: "[website]/media/[file]". When looking in my Docker folder directory, the file exists at the specified path, so I am not sure what is going on.

This is the server configuration I believe may need to be adjusted.

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name  [website].com  www.[website].com;
  root /dist/;
  index index.html;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/keeptrackapp.ca/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/keeptrackapp.ca/privkey.pem;
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

  # backend urls
  location ~ ^/(admin|api|accounts|media|registration|auth|api-auth) {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://backend;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  }

  location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; }
  location = /sitemap.xml { log_not_found off; }
  location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; }

  location /media {
    alias /media;
  }

  location /static {
    alias /app/static;
  }

  # frontend
  location /index.html {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
  }

  location @rewrites {
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.html last;
  }
}
```

I have tried a few different variations for the media location including...

```
location /media {
  alias /media;
}

location /media/ {
  alias /media/;
}

location /media {
  root /media;
}

location /media/ {
  root /media/;
}

location ^~ /media {
  root /media;
}
```

This is not an extensive list. I have tried every variation I could think of. Please provide some insight if I am approaching this wrong.

Cheers.

Comment: I still haven't found any methods to make this work properly. I don't understand why though. I have tried every configuration I can find online, made sure my folder permissions are not being blocked but downloading still will not work. I came close by adding "location ~ ^/media/(pdf|jpg)" but when downloading the file won't open and is damaged. Any ideas?